# Multiplicative structure without unique prime factorisation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The subset $N:=\{3n+1\colon n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is closed under multiplication. 4, 10 and 25 are prime numbers in $N$. We have $100=4\cdot 25=10\cdot 10$, hence factorisation with prime numbers in $N$ is not unique.

Is there a subset $M$ of $\mathbb{N}$ that is closed under multiplication such that there is a number $n\in M$ with $n=\prod_{i=1}^jp_i=\prod_{i=1}^kq_i$ where $j<k$ and the $p_i$'s and $q_i$'s are prime numbers in $M$?

If there is no such subset in $\mathbb{N}$, is there another example where the number of prime elements in a factorisation is not unique?

Comment: An element is *prime* if $p\mid ab\Rightarrow p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$. An element is *irreducible* if it has no factorization into a product of more than one noninvertible element. In the set of naturals with residue $1$ mod $3$, the element $4$ divides $10\cdot10$ but doesn't divide $10$, hence $4$ is not prime in this structure. You are talking about *irreducible*, not *prime*. This is understandable since we usually define prime numbers as irreducible natural numbers before exposing students to the more advanced, separate definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Take $M = \{5n+1 : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Then the number $12996$ has two prime factorizations, one into $2$ and one into $3$ primes: $$ 12996 = 76 \times 171 = 6 \times 6 \times 361.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! How did you find this example?

Comment: I tried to make a product of 3 primes $A$, $B$, $C$ equal to a product of 2 primes $D$, $E$. Then I tried $A = p_1q_1$, $B= p_2q_2$, $C=p_3q_3$, $D=p_1p_2p_3$, $E=q_1q_2q_3$ where the $p_i$ and $q_i$ are prime numbers in $\mathcal{N}$ (note that $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ and $E$ cannot be primes in $\mathbb{N}$ themselves). What's left is to find the $p_i$, $q_i$ outside $M$ such that $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ and $E$ are in $M$.